# Create Serenity's index.html when clicking on Run/Debug in IntelliJ

Tags: api, rest, testing, intellij-idea, serenity-bdd

I have created a testing project. I would like to use Serenity. It seems it is working fine (told by fancy "Test Passed" messages). My goal is to create index.html serenity report by running Run/Debug option and not using `mvn clean verify`.

this is what I have in pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.whatever.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>whatever</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.serenity}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-threetenbp-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-web-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${version.serenity}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.serenity}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${version.serenity}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <swagger-annotations-version>2.0.0</swagger-annotations-version>
        <spring-web-version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring-web-version>
        <jackson-version>2.8.9</jackson-version>
        <jackson-threetenbp-version>2.6.4</jackson-threetenbp-version>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
        <junit-version>4.13.1</junit-version>
        <version.serenity>2.3.8</version.serenity>
        <version.serenity.maven>1.0.47</version.serenity.maven>
        <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>2.19.1</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.3.8</serenity.maven.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Is there any option to do this? Maybe by using "Edit Configurations..." option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to run Maven goal that would generate the report in [**Before launch**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html#before-launch-options) section of Run/Debug Configuration.

Comment: There is **Run Maven Goal** option.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. This is for someone who would need something like this in the future.

In MAVEN Projects Execute Maven Goal and insert `-T4 serenity:reports -Dserenity.reports=single-page-html`. This should create report after Run/Debug . Be careful you need to do it after every run. This should be done automatically somehow thought.